# How to execute a script from a browser?

Tags: scripts, remote

I've  abash script on my machine and my client needs to use this script through remote connections. I don't want them to access my source code so I have to give them a tool i.e a html page through which they can only *execute* my script without being able to view or modify the script.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you need a browser for it? Why isn't Nautilus good enough?

Comment: Do you mean maybe by PHP or something similar?

Comment: @derHugo- Yes PHP or XML something like that. Is there any possibilities with those platforms.

Comment: @Rinzwind- I edited my question for why would i need a browser in specific.

Comment: Is the script supposed to do something on the server or the client system? You can't keep the code secret if it's supposed to run on the client system. You could port the script to a compiled language, deliver only the binary executable to the client and thus “obfuscate” the source code.

Comment: @DavidFoerster- the script will not present on the client server, it will be with my own server. I'm planning to give them a webpage (something like a front-end  tool) they can execute the script through that font-end. So that i can ensure that my script invisible to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not by default from a browser unless you can find and exploit a bug that lets you. Browsers are sandboxed to prevent executing code on the system itself.

What you would need to execute a script from a browser:

- Apache. There is a package called lampserver that installs a working webserver with apache, mysql, and support for using php, perl, python.
- A coding language supported by your browser to create something clickable (javascript, php, etc) in the browser.
- Software on the server to act on that clickable something and execute that script you want to start.